# Add text between two charts on a BarChart

Tags: labeling, charts, text

I have the following list :

```
Mdx = {{73024.8`, 28427.1`}, {51486.5`, 26994.3`}, {30663.3`, 
19068.`}, {42428.1`, 26226.2`}, {16337.4`, 17798.5`}, {46855.6`, 
39230.6`}};
```

List that I printed in the form of a BarChart:

```
MdxPlot = BarChart[Mdx, ImageSize -> 400, ChartStyle -> {LightGray, Automatic},ChartLayout -> "Grouped", ChartLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"EKV", "ASV"}, 
 LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
     Background -> White] &)], {Right, Top}], AxesLabel -> {"", "Mdx [kNm]"}, ChartLabels -> {{"K1-1", "K2-3", "K1-4", "K1-5", "K1-6", "K1-7"}, 
None}, PlotLabel -> "X-Richtung", PlotRange -> {Full, {Automatic, Max[Mdx] + 10000}}]
```

Which give me this nice result :

[image]

Now I would like to place a list of value between the orange and the blue charts, this list represents the percentage difference between the two values.

```
DeltaX = {-61.07199198080653`, -47.57013974537015`, -37.81491228928393`, -38.18672059319177`,8.943283509003882`, -16.27340168517744`, -20.83293776466232`}
```

Wich would give :

[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use options of `Labeled` like the following:

```
Mdx = {{73024.8`, 28427.1`}, {51486.5`, 26994.3`}, {30663.3`, 
    19068.`}, {42428.1`, 26226.2`}, {16337.4`, 17798.5`}, {46855.6`, 
    39230.6`}};
dat1 = Mdx[[All, 1]];
dat2 = Mdx[[All, 2]];
dat3 = Transpose[{dat1, dat2}];
DeltaX = {-61.07199198080653`, -47.57013974537015`, \
-37.81491228928393`, -38.18672059319177`, 
   8.943283509003882`, -16.27340168517744`};
dat4 = MapThread[
   Labeled[#1, StringForm["      ``%", NumberForm[#2, 3]], Above, Red,
      12] &, {dat3, DeltaX}];
dat = Transpose[{dat1, dat2}];

MdxPlot = 
 BarChart[dat4, ImageSize -> 400, 
  ChartStyle -> {LightGray, Automatic}, ChartLayout -> "Grouped", 
  ChartLegends -> 
   Placed[LineLegend[{"EKV", "ASV"}, 
     LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
         Background -> White] &)], {Right, Top}], 
  AxesLabel -> {"", "Mdx [kNm]"}, 
  ChartLabels -> {{"K1-1", "K2-3", "K1-4", "K1-5", "K1-6", "K1-7"}, 
    None}, PlotLabel -> "X-Richtung", 
  PlotRange -> {Full, {Automatic, Max[Mdx] + 10000}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

```
percentdiffs = PercentForm /@ (- Subtract @@@ Mdx/Mdx[[All, 1]]);

BarChart[Thread[Labeled[Mdx, Style[#, Red, 14] & /@ percentdiffs, Above]], 
 ImageSize -> 500, 
 ChartLayout -> "Grouped", 
 ChartLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"EKV", "ASV"}, 
      LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, Background -> White] &)], 
    {Right, Top}], 
 AxesLabel -> {"", "Mdx [kNm]"}, 
 ChartLabels -> { {"K1-1", "K2-3", "K1-4", "K1-5", "K1-6", "K1-7"}, None}, 
 PlotLabel -> "X-Richtung", 
 PlotRange -> {Full, {Automatic, Max[Mdx] + 10000}}]
```

[image]

Add the option `ChartStyle -> {{LightGray, ColorData[97]@1}}` to get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is as follows. Use the following code:

```
Manipulate[
 DynamicModule[{pt1 = {1, 0}, pt2 = {4, 0}},
  loc = Graphics[{Blue, Thin, Circle[{0, 0}, 2]}, ImageSize -> 20];
  Column[{
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1, pt2}],
     Dynamic@
      Show[{
        
        (* Here your graphics starts *)
        Show[{
          MdxPlot,
          
          Graphics[{Text[Style["-61.07", 14, Red], pt1], 
            Text[Style["-47.57", 14, Red], pt2]}]
          }]
        (* Here your graphics ends *)
          }, ImageSize -> sz]
     , Appearance -> loc ],
                        
    Button["Print the list of points", Clear[points]; 
     points = {pt1, pt2}; Print[points]]
            }]
                            ], {sz, 250, 650}]
```

Please see that the code making the graphics you are working on is included between the lines: `(* Here your graphics starts *)` and `(* Here your graphics ends *)`. The rest of the code is needed to comfortably position the text on your graphics.

Step one: evaluate the code. It returns the manipulator:

[image]

Using the slider `sz` make a comfortable size of the image.

Step two: Find two locators with the form of circles containing the texts at the bottom of the image and move them to the desired places.

[image]

Step three: Press the button "Print the list of points" at the bottom. This returns the list with the positions of the locators. The list is under the bottom of the manipulator.

[image]

Copy-paste the first of the coordinates of these points instead of pt1 and the second - instead of pt2 into the line

```
Graphics[{Text[Style["-37.81", 14, Red], pt1], 
  Text[Style["-38.18", 14, Red], pt2]}]
```

of the code.

Step four: Add the functions `Text[Style["-61.07", 14, Red], pt1], Text[Style["-47.57", 14, Red]` into the graphics statement and evaluate.

Repeat the procedure until you have introduced all text elements.

As soon as you have introduced all text elements into your plot, copy the part of the code staying between the lines: `(* Here your graphics starts *)` and `(* Here your graphics ends *)` and paste it somewhere in your notebook. Evaluate it. Done.

Have fun!